# getView not returning view parameters

Tags: java, oop, android-view, android-adapterview, getview

I have an `AdapterView` that displays a list and headers that separate different list categories. The list is populated by a SQLite database with user input. So far everything is working.

I want to remove the headers when there are no items in the header's category. The code is as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (viewType == TYPE_NORMAL) 
    {
        // If the convertView is a textview (group), ignore it
        if (convertView instanceof TextView)
        {
            convertView = null;
        }

        final int mapCursorPos = getInteralItemPosition(position);
        return super.getView(mapCursorPos, convertView, parent);
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Check if it's a text view
        TextView text;
        if (convertView == null || !(convertView instanceof TextView)) 
        {
            ((ListView) parent).setDivider(null);
            ((ListView) parent).setDividerHeight(0);
            text = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_group, parent, false);
        } 
        else
        {
            text = (TextView) convertView;
        }


        final String group = groupsIndexer.get(position).getName(resources);

        //Code to hide menu title.
        text.setText(group);
        text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        myCursor = getCursor();
        initCols(myCursor);

        myCursor.moveToFirst();

        while (myCursor.isAfterLast() == false) 
        {

            String groupCursor = getGroup(myCursor).getName(resources);

            if (groupCursor == group) 
            {
                    text.setHeight(12);
                    text.setPadding(20, 10, 0, 10);
                    text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                        
            }
            myCursor.moveToNext();
        }           
        return text;
    }
}
```

So, as you can see I started by setting the text as invisible and then querying the database to check if there is any item in their specific category and if there is I set the visibility to visible.

However when returning, the method seems to ignore whatever's in the while loop. Is it not possible to format each textview object individually through `getView()` like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that should put you in the right direction.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class GroupedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private static final int TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_GROUP  = 1;
    private static final int MAX_TYPES   = 2;

    private final Context              mContext;
    private final LayoutInflater       mInflater;
    private final ContactManager       mContactManager;
    private final ArrayList<GroupItem> mItems          = new ArrayList<GroupItem>();
    private final DataSetObserver      mDataSetObserver = new MyDataSetObserver();

    private boolean mDataValid = false;
    private Cursor  mCursor    = null;

    private int mIndexId;
    private int mIndexSummary;
    private int mIndexType;
    private int mIndexSender;
    private int mIndexReciever;
    private int mIndexCompleted;
    private int mIndexCompletedBy;



    public GroupedListAdapter(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mContactManager = new ContactManager(context);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void changeCursor(Cursor newCursor)
    {
        if(newCursor == mCursor){
            return;
        }
        Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
        if(oldCursor != null) {
            if(mDataSetObserver != null){
                oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }
        }
        mCursor = newCursor;
        if(newCursor != null){
            if(mDataSetObserver != null){
                newCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }

            mIndexId          = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseContract.Task.Columns._ID);
            mIndexSummary     = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseContract.Task.Columns.SUMMARY);
            mIndexType        = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseContract.Task.Columns.TYPE);
            mIndexSender      = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseContract.Task.Columns.SENDER);
            mIndexReciever    = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseContract.Task.Columns.RECIEVER);
            mIndexCompleted   = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseContract.Task.Columns.COMPLETED);
            mIndexCompletedBy = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseContract.Task.Columns.COMPLETED_BY);

            // calculate types and index mappings

            /*
             * 1. Sent (5)
             * 2. Item 5
             * 3. Item 6
             * 4. Received (9)
             * 5. Item 9
             * 6. Today (1)
             * 7. Item 1
             * 8. Item 2
             * 9. Item 3
             * 
             */

            // allocate 
            int count = newCursor.getCount();
            mItems.ensureCapacity(count);
            if(newCursor.moveToFirst()){
                int i = 0;
                do{
                    mItems.add(new GroupItem(getGroupId(newCursor), i, TYPE_NORMAL));
                    i++;
                }while(newCursor.moveToNext());
            }

            Collections.sort(mItems);

            int lastGroupId = -1;
            for(int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++){
                final GroupItem item = mItems.get(i);
                if(lastGroupId != item.group_id){
                    mItems.add(i, new GroupItem(item, TYPE_GROUP));
                    lastGroupId = item.group_id;
                }
            }

            mDataValid = true;

            // notify the observers about the new cursor
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else{
            mDataValid = false;

            mIndexId          = -1;
            mIndexSummary     = -1;
            mIndexType        = -1;
            mIndexSender      = -1;
            mIndexReciever    = -1;
            mIndexCompleted   = -1;
            mIndexCompletedBy = -1;

            mItems.clear();

            // notify the observers about the lack of a data set
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }

        if(oldCursor != null) {
            oldCursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
        }

        GroupItem item = mItems.get(position);

        if(!mCursor.moveToPosition(item.position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
        }

        final View view;
        if(convertView == null) {
            if(item.type == TYPE_GROUP){
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_group, parent, false);
            }
            else if(item.type == TYPE_NORMAL){
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_item, parent, false);
            }
            else{
                throw new IllegalStateException("Bad TaskItem type");
            }
        }
        else{
            view = convertView;
        }


        if(item.type == TYPE_GROUP){
            TextView textGroup = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.task_group);
            textGroup.setText(mContext.getString(item.group_id));
        }
        else if(item.type == TYPE_NORMAL){
            TextView textTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
            TextView textDescr = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.task_description);

            String desc;

            String type  = mCursor.getString(mIndexType);
            if(type.equals(DatabaseContract.Task.TASK_TYPE_OWNER)){
                desc = mContext.getString(R.string.desc_example);
            }
            else if(type.equals(DatabaseContract.Task.TASK_TYPE_RECEV)){
                final String sender = mCursor.getString(mIndexSender);
                final String name = mContactManager.getContactName(sender);
                desc = (name != null) ? name : sender;
            }
            else{
                final String receiver = mCursor.getString(mIndexReciever);
                final String name = mContactManager.getContactName(receiver);
                desc = (name != null) ? name : receiver;
            }

            textDescr.setText(desc);

            String title = mCursor.getString(mIndexSummary);
            textTitle.setText(Character.toUpperCase(title.charAt(0)) + title.substring(1));
            if(mCursor.getInt(mIndexCompleted) != 0){
                textTitle.setPaintFlags(textTitle.getPaintFlags() |  Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            }
            else{
                textTitle.setPaintFlags(textTitle.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            }
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor getItem(int position)
    {
        if(mDataValid && mCursor != null){
            mCursor.moveToPosition(mItems.get(position).position);
            return mCursor;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        if(mDataValid && mCursor != null){
            if(mCursor.moveToPosition(mItems.get(position).position)){
                return mCursor.getLong(mIndexId);
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if(mDataValid && mCursor != null){
            return mItems.get(position).type;
        }
        else{
            return IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return MAX_TYPES;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        if(mDataValid && mCursor != null){
            return mItems.size();
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getCursor()
    {
        return mCursor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private int getGroupId(Cursor c)
    {
        if(c.getString(mIndexType).equals(DatabaseContract.Task.TASK_TYPE_SENT)){
            return R.string.group_sent;
        }
        else if(c.getString(mIndexType).equals(DatabaseContract.Task.TASK_TYPE_RECEV)){
            return R.string.group_received;
        }
        else{
            long time  = c.getLong(mIndexCompletedBy);
            long delta = (time - System.currentTimeMillis());

            if(delta <= DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS){
                return R.string.group_asap;
            }
            else if(delta <= DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS){
                return R.string.group_today;
            }
            else if(delta <= (DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS * 2)){
                return R.string.group_tomorrow;
            }
            else if(delta <= DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS){
                return R.string.group_this_week;
            }
            else if(delta <= (DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS * 2)){
                return R.string.group_next_week;
            }
            else{
                return R.string.group_someday;
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver
    {
        @Override
        public void onChanged()
        {
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated()
        {
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }

    private static class GroupItem implements Comparable<GroupItem>
    {
        public int group_id;
        public int position;
        public int type;


        public GroupItem(int group_id, int position, int type)
        {
            this.group_id = group_id;
            this.position = position;
            this.type     = type;
        }

        public GroupItem(GroupItem item, int type)
        {
            this.group_id = item.group_id;
            this.position = item.position;
            this.type     = type;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(GroupItem another)
        {
            return group_id < another.group_id ? -1 : (group_id == another.group_id ? 0 : 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `groupCursor == group` to `groupCursor.equals(group)`.

BTW I suggest to load the data in another thread, not in the UI thread and especially not in the getView method, because it can be called LOT of times by the ListView